# Azure SQL accent sensitive object names

Tags: azure-sql-database

We have an on-premise database that we want to upload to Azure using the Data Migration Assistant.
Our databases use the collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI. We use accents in some of our table and column names. When writing queries in SSMS, if we omit the accent in a table name, it still works but it gives an error on Azure. Is there a way to configure Azure SQL to be accent insensitive on object names while still being accent insensitive on Text data?

For exemple, if I have a table named [Paramètres] and then I execute the following statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Parametres]
```

it works in SSMS but it doesn't work with Azure. I get a "Invalid object name" error

Answer (score 0):

The accent sensitive/insensitive is depended on the database collation. Collations in SQL Server provide sorting rules, case, and accent sensitivity properties for your data.

Please ref：[Collation and Unicode support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15)。

You could run bellow query check if the collation is accent sensitive or insensitive:

```
IF 'a' = 'á' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
SELECT 'Values are the same'
ELSE
SELECT 'Values are different'
```

**AS** is Accent sensitive and **AI** Accent insensitive. For example, your on-premise database collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI` and it's accent insensitive.

Please run bellow query to check your Azure SQL database collation :

```
SELECT CONVERT (varchar, SERVERPROPERTY('collation')) AS 'Server Collation';
```

We cannot change the collation for an Azure SQL Database after it is created. So there is no way to configure Azure SQL to be accent insensitive.

Suggestion is that don't DMA to migrate your on-premise database to an exist Azure SQL  database. Please using import DACPAC or SSMS: deploy database to Azure SQL Database:
[image]

Comment: The azure database is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI while the master/server collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. I believe all object names are in that database which is why it is accent sensitive on the object names. I tried both, the DMA and deploying using SSMS and I got the same result.

Comment: I edited my question to add an example to clarify my problem.

Comment: SSMS is just a query tool. What do you mean it doesn't work with Azure? As I understand, it works with your on-premise database, and not work for Azure SQL database.

Comment: You understood correctly. I think the problem is that Azure SQL has a collation Accent Sensitive at the server level.

Comment: I deployed my database using SSMS, I verified the collation on the database it is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI but it is still accent sensitive to object names like table names, field names and stored procedure names.

Comment: @AlecDaraiche Sorry for that! I tried and get the same result! I doubt Azure SQL database doesn't support accent insensitive even if I create it with accent insensitive collation! I can't find any Azure document to prove that.